# Update based on conditions in SQL Server using self join

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like below in SQL Server 2008.

```
ID| ParentID| InvID |IsIntTr|   IsTR
1 |   NULL  |     1 |  NULL |   NULL
2 |      1  |     2 |  NULL |   NULL
3 |      1  |     1 |  NULL |   NULL
```

My requirement is: 
If ParentID is populated 
Compare the parent’s InvID to the child’s InvID.  If they are populated and they are the same value then set the IsIntTr=1 and IsTr=0.  Otherwise, set the IsIntTr=NULL and the IsTr =1 
Else (i.e ParentID is null) 
 Set IsIntTr=NULL and IsTr=NULL

I have written the following SQL update query, however, it does not work as expected:

```
UPDATE child SET

IsIntTr =   
   CASE WHEN child.ParentID IS NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN child.InvID = parent.InvID AND child.ParentID IS NOT NULL
                THEN 1 ELSE NULL END,
IsTr     =  
    CASE WHEN child.ParentID IS NULL THEN NULL  
        WHEN child.InvID = parent.InvID AND child.ParentID IS NOT NULL
                THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    from    MyTable child (NOLOCK),     
            MyTable parent (NOLOCK)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Saying _it does not work as expected_ which case do you mean?

Comment: as pointed out by Taras, since 'where' clause was missing, it only updated rows where ID = ParentID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had `Where` missing at the end.

Try this:

```
UPDATE child SET
IsIntTr =   
   CASE WHEN child.InvID = parent.InvID THEN 1
        ELSE NULL
   END,

IsTr     =  
   CASE WHEN child.InvID = parent.InvID THEN 0
        ELSE 1
   END
from    MyTable child (NOLOCK),     
        MyTable parent (NOLOCK)
WHERE
  child.ParentId = Parent.Id
```

or in [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3a63/1).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the query. However, I forgot to mention that IsTR and IsIntTR will have initial values (1 or 0) and not NULL. So, in this case, when I execute your query, it only updates where ParentID is not null and fails to update (both IsTR and IsIntTR) with NULL, where ParentID is NULL. So do I need 2 updates?

Comment: yeah I think you can pre-process by setting all Is-* columns to `NULL`.

Comment: Nope! I can't do that... that is a pre-populated table :-(

Comment: So another problem is that you want to also update those that have ParentId `NULL`, right? Then you should specify what is the rule of that update. What if you have one parent and 2 childs with different `InvId`s - how do you update parent row then?
A side note: Things like _I forgot to mention_ require posting another question usually, otherwise its infinite process to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    ParentID INT,
    InvID INT,
    IsIntTr INT,
    IsTR INT
)

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT NULL, 1, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, NULL, NULL

UPDATE #temp SET #temp.IsIntTr = 
    CASE WHEN tbl.InvID_A = tbl.InvID_B THEN 1 ELSE NULL END,
    #temp.IsTR = CASE WHEN tbl.InvID_A = tbl.InvID_B THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
FROM (SELECT A.ID, A.ParentID, A.InvID AS InvID_A, B.InvID AS InvID_B, A.IsIntTr, A.IsTR FROM #temp A
INNER Join #temp B
ON A.ParentID = B.ID) AS tbl
WHERE #temp.id = tbl.ID
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the query. However, I forgot to mention that IsTR and IsIntTR will have initial values (1 or 0) and not NULL. So, in this case, when I execute your query, it only updates where ParentID is not null and fails to update (both IsTR and IsIntTR) with NULL, where ParentID is NULL. So do I need 2 updates?

Comment: Yes. You need an update statement where ParentID IS NULL